# How to redirect from an old url to a new one after removing the extension through htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am using the following snippet to remove the php extension of my pages:

```
RewriteEngine on
rewritecond %{http_host} ^example.com [nc]
rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Now I want to do an oldpage to a new page. Something like http://www.example.com/oldpage should redirect permanently(301) to http://www.example.com/newpage

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use redirect match :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/oldpage$ /newpage
```

Comment: `RewriteEngine on`
`rewritecond %{http_host} ^example.com [nc]`
`rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]`
`RedirectMatch 301 ^/oldpage$ /newpage`

This is how I tried but it's still opening the oldpage

Comment: you can put this above the RewriteEngine On line

Comment: Tried but no success. Still the old page opens up

Comment: Do u have anyother rules ?

Comment: Just what's mentioned above in the question.